# Socket.io won't emit to a room

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to create a chat lobby where users can create a private room, and others can join through a uuid. This is built with node.js and socket.io, and it seems as if `io.to(room).emit('event', 'data')` and `io.sockets.to(room).emit('event', 'data')` **do not work**, while `io.emit('event', 'data')` works. My code can be found below:

```js
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('createRoom', function(data) {
      let room = new Room(data).create();

      let id = room.data.uuid
      socket.join(id)

      io.to(id).emit('roomcreated', {data: data, msg: 'Room Created'}) //Does not work!
      io.emit('roomcreated', {data: data, msg: 'Room Created'}) //This Works
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A common problem with `.join()` is that it is actually asynchronous.  It does not immediately complete.  This is probably because it's designed to work with the multiple process, redis-based adapter that supports clustering and there the join process has to be asynchronous because it's communicating with other processes.

You can fix your issue, by sending a callback to `.join()` and only emitting to the room AFTER it has finished joining.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('createRoom', function(data) {
      let room = new Room(data).create();

      let id = room.data.uuid
      socket.join(id, (err) => {
         if (err) {
             // do something here if the join fails
             console.log(err);
             return;
         }
         
         // call this only after the join has completed
         io.to(id).emit('roomcreated', {data: data, msg: 'Room Created'});
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried using this, but it still seems to not work. I know for sure that the socket is in the room as in the callback I added `console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms[id])`, and I get an output of `Room { sockets: { '0.897845087222128': true }, length: 1 }`.

Comment: Are you sure the new client that just joined the room is already listening for the `roomcreated` message? And, you're 100% sure it doesn't receive that message?  Also, what type is `room.data.uuid`?  Is it a string?

Comment: room.data.uuid is a randomly generated string. I make sure it is unique and all too. The client has `socket.on('roomcreated', function(data) { console.log(data); })`. The client does receive this whenever i call `io.emit`, but not `io.to(id).emit` for some reason. I have also tried variations in calling the function like `io.in(id).emit` and `io.sockets.to(id).emit` and none seem to work.

Comment: @LukeSchwartz - If the `io.to(id).emit('roomcreated', ....)` is INSIDE the callback for `socket.join()`, then it should work.  The message will be sent.  You can trace into `io.to(id)` in the debugger and watch what it does (see if it finds the room).  If so, then trace into `.emit()` and watch to see if it sends a message to the one socket in the room.

Comment: @LukeSchwartz - One other possibility.  Are you 100% sure that this particular socket is staying connected and your page isn't somehow reloading causing a different socket to get loaded?  You can add an event handler with a `console.log()` in it for the `socket.on('disconnect', ...)` event to log any disconnects just to make sure there's not something funny happen with the socket lifetime.

Comment: I ran it through a debugger and made sure that there was no disconnect. It looks like it finds the room okay, but won't emit to that room...

Comment: I tested the `io.in(id).emit('roomcreated')` outside of the `socket.on('createRoom')` event and it worked... any insight as to why it wont work inside?

Comment: Well, you can run an experiment from within the callback to do `setTimeout(() => io.in(id).emit('roomcreated'), 100)` and see if a further delay allows something else to finish so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure entirely what's not working with `io.in(id).emit('roomCreated', {d: data});` but I found a work around method.

I created an object of all sockets called SOCKET_LIST, and an array for each room that holds the id of that socket:

```js
var SOCKET_LIST = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {

  socket.id = Math.random();
  SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;

  socket.on('createRoom', function(data) {
      let room = new Room(data).create();
      room.data.users.push(socket.id)

      let id = room.data.uuid
      socket.join(id, (err) => {
        if(err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        room.data.users.forEach(i => {
          SOCKET_LIST[i].emit('roomcreated', {data: data, msg: 'Room Created'})
        })
      })

  });
});
```